# C++ string array & Accessing chars

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

In C++, I'm trying to create string array. And also I want to access chars and change them like this:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    char lines[4][n+1];
    int color = 0;
    for(int a = 0; a < n; a++){
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            lines[i][a] = (char) (color % 25 + 97);
            if(i == 1 || i == 3){
                color++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << lines[0] << endl << lines[1] << endl << lines[2] << endl << lines[3];
    return 0;
}
```

When i want it to print all of "lines[i]" there appears some unknown characters.

Expected:

> aceg
>
> aceg
>
> bdfh
>
> bdfh

Output:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR4Y4.png)

> aceg'aceg■bdfh
>
> aceg■bdfh
>
> bdfh
>
> bdfh

Do you know the reason? (I checked my whole code many times, it causes something i don't know about array of char arrays I thought)

Are there any other ways to do this? (**If possible** without libraries like its in C)

**Edit**

I added all of my code to this message.

Comment: You need to understand what "want to print" entails.

Comment: Strings are null-terminated...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  Please show how you are printing your arrays.  Unless you've done something you've not shown, printing them as if they are strings will show the sort of behaviour you're seeing.  Since you don't show any code changing `color`, you should be getting the same value (`'a'`) in every cell.  When you omit key parts of the code, people become frustrated — it is hard to help you when code is missing.  Please read up on how to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  What's the value in `n`?

Comment: @KerrekSB: That code is also valid C++. Accusing the OP of lying is a bit much.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Without knowing whether `n` is a constant expression, I'm not sure it's valid C++...

Comment: @KerrekSB: And that's your basis for accusing the OP of lying? Perhaps I'm missing something; is that less rude than it seems to be?

Comment: I'm new at C & C++ & Stackoverflow. So I made some mistakes. Sorry for my faults. And sorry for late answering. I wasn't expecting answers quickly.

@JonathanLeffler Thank you, I will read it. I added whole code.

DennisMeng I fixed the problem by adding '\0' to the last item of each array as you said. Thank you.

KerrekSB Thank you, too.

Comment: By the way, there are no variable-length arrays in C++, so your code isn't strictly valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>I can't be sure without seeing exactly how you are printing, but if you're just printing via something like `printf("%s\n", lines[i]);`, then</del> your problem is because you forgot to null-terminate your strings.

Make sure you do something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    lines[i][n] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Pardon, I guess if you're using C++ then `std::cout << lines[i];`

Comment: This is probably right, since the OP has the conspicuous array size `n + 1` in her code...

Comment: That, and the output that the OP is possible if `lines[0][n]` and `lines[1][n]` are not null, but `lines[3][n]` and `lines[4][n]` *are*.

Comment: Where can I check this problem as answered? (I already checked green tick.)
Also it was that what I don't know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

for(int i = 0; i != 4; ++i)
{
    fwrite(lines[i], 1, n, stdout);
    fputc('\n', stdout);
}
```

Or in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

for(int i = 0; i != 4; ++i)
{
    std::cout << std::string(lines[i], n) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: While that might be true, what if the OP's problem is that he's not printing the same way? This wouldn't help the OP understand why he sees the behavior he does.

Comment: @DennisMeng: By all means post an answer that explains the OP's problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
aceg'aceg■bdfh

aceg■bdfh

bdfh

bdfh
```

See you output  then you can find :

```
line[0] in fact print line[0] & line [1] & line[2].
line[1] in fact print line[1] & line [2].
```

That means you "string" didn't have the right stop flag.

use `line[i][n] = '\0'` Or `char[i][4] = '\0'` if you only store 4 char.